# Perl - Passar dados JSON para variável e comparar com IF

Tags: json, perl

Bom dia,

Tenho um request que faço em uma API usando GET (LWP::UserAgent), os dados são retornados em um JSON, no JSON são retornados até dois resultados no máximo da seguinte forma :

```
{"status":1,"time":1507891855,"response":{"prices":{"nome1\u2122":
{"preco1":1111,"preco2":1585,"preco3":1099},"nome2":
{"preco1":519,"preco2":731,"preco3":491}}}}
```

Dump :

```
$VAR1 = {
      'status' => 1,
      'time' => 1507891855,
      'response' => {
                      'prices' => {
                                    'nome1' => {
                                                 'preco1' => 1111,
                                                 'preco3' => 1099,
                                                 'preco2' => 1585
                                               },
                                    'nome2' => {
                                                 'preco3' => 491,
                                                 'preco1' => 519,
                                                 'preco2' => 731
                                               }
                                  }
                    }
    };
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é :

Pegar esses dados e salvar em uma variável para fazer uma comparação usando IF com outra variável que já tem o nome armazenado, a comparação seria com o nome1/nome2 e se for verdadeira com a outra variável ele iria pegar o preco2 e preco3 para printar tudo.

O meu maior problema no caso é que alguns desses nomes no JSON contém caracteres  como (TradeMark) que vem como \u2122 ( alguns casos são outros caracteres ), com isso eu não consigo fazer a comparação com o nome da outra váriavel que já está com o nome correto

```
nome1™
```

Se eu conseguisse apenas salvar o JSON já "convertido" os caracteres me ajudaria a me virar com o resto.

Basicamente depois que fazer o request para a API eu quero salvar o conteudo em uma variável já convertendo todos os \u2122 para o seu respectivo caractere ( essa é a parte que eu não sei fazer no Perl )  e depois usando uma outra variavél comparar se os nomes são iguais para mostrar o preço.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda e qualquer dúvida por favor me digam que tento explicar novamente de outra forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido usando a seguinte função:

```
use utf8;
use JSON::XS;

my $name = "nome1™";
my $var1 = decode_json $utf8_encoded_json_text;

# Compare with name in $name
if( defined $var1->{'response'}->{'prices'}->{$name} ) {
# Do something with the name that matches
my $match = $var1->{'response'}->{'prices'}->{$name};

print $match->{'preco1'}, "\n";
}
```